# No Microsoft Access driver in Mac OS X ColdFusion 9 Developer Edition - can’t create a datasource for Access

Tags: macos, ms-access, coldfusion, datasource, jet

I have CF9 Developer Edition installed on Mac OS X 10.6. I have set up datasources successfully to the localhosts MySQL. However, I have taken on a website which uses a Microsoft Access database: fine on the actual server, but to work on the site offline I need to set up the datasource to talk to the Access database.

For some reason, there is no Microsoft Access option in the Add Driver list when setting up a new datasource in the CF admin.

Any ideas on what I need to do would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mac driver for Access available.
You can upconvert your database to the free edition of SQL Server. It's probably a good idea to convince your customer to migrate from Access to SQL Server anyways.

Comment: Or convert database to MySQL or PostgreSQL. Both are free and both work great with ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'd very much second the comments above regarding getting off of Access if you can, there does appear to be a couple of type-4 (pure java) JDBC access drivers (although I've not used them)

http://www.hxtt.com/access.html

This article links to two drivers. Neither are free but both have evaluation periods on them which may get you through what you need to do.
http://www.razorsql.com/articles/ms_access_mac_os_x.html

You should be able to use these as custom JDBC datasources in ColdFusion.

let us know if you have any success.

Answer (score 0):

There's proprietary **read-only** driver [available](http://www.actualtech.com/product_access.php).